# Access camera through using web apps

Tags: android, html, cordova, camera

I'm planning to develop web app using html.(using html tool like phonegap).
I want to take picture and upload to the hosted site. can i access phone camera using the html page?

if i can't do this any suitable suggestions to do this.

Thankz for any help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can both take pictures and upload using phonegap

 check out http://docs.phonegap.com/en/1.0.0/phonegap_camera_camera.md.html
and http://docs.phonegap.com/en/1.0.0/phonegap_file_file.md.html#FileTransfer